# Include additional files in .bashrc

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, bash

I have some stuff I want to perform in .bashrc which I would prefer to exist in another file on the system. How can I include this file into .bashrc?

Comment: Should this question be posted on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Add `source /whatever/file` (or `. /whatever/file`) into `.bashrc` where you want the other file included.

Comment: You should handle non-existence gracefully.  eg, either check existence ( test -r path && . path ) or ignore errors ( . path 2> /dev/null )

Comment: @William Pursell IMO it's easier to test once, then to write code for cases, that 99.99% never happen.

Comment: @Daniel I disagree.  Things that happen .01% of the time may occur thousands of times per second.  And having a .bashrc on an NFS mounted $HOME could mean the failure rate of sourcing a file is much higher than .01%

Answer (score 78):

To prevent errors you need to first check to make sure the file exists.  Then source the file.  Do something like this.

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f $HOME/.bashrc_aliases ]; then
    . $HOME/.bashrc_aliases
fi
```

Comment: also at the end of the .bashrc_aliases  or whatever file I'm sourcing I echo out a statement like

echo "Aliases loaded"

Comment: I thought to myself: "~ is $HOME, right?" Alas, `if [ -f ~/.bashrc_aliases ];` does not work.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a one liner!

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc_aliases ] && . $HOME/.bashrc_aliases
```

Fun fact: shell (and most other languages) are lazy. If there are a series of conditions joined by a conjunction (aka "and" aka `&&`) then evaluation will begin from the left to the right. The moment one of the conditions is false, the rest of the expressions won't be evaluated, effectively "short circuiting" other expressions.

Thus, you can put a command you want to execute on the right of a conditional, it won't execute unless every condition on the left is evaluated as "true."

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple files you want to load that may or may not exist, you can keep it somewhat elegant by using a for loop.

```
files=(somefile1 somefile2)
path="$HOME/path/to/dir/containing/files/"
for file in ${files[@]}
do 
    file_to_load=$path$file
    if [ -f "$file_to_load" ];
    then
        . $file_to_load
        echo "loaded $file_to_load"
    fi
done
```

The output would look like:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
loaded $HOME/path/to/dir/containing/files/somefile1
loaded $HOME/path/to/dir/containing/files/somefile2
```

Comment: Surely you don't need to check for file existence again inside the loop? (Unless you have a very dynamic list of files on disk)

Comment: There is only one check for file existence. If your current work environment doesn't have the file described in the list, it will simply error on that file load and create visual noise. A more ideal approach would be to get a list of files, then loop through that, rather than defining a static list.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to check version first and assign variable for path config:

```
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
  filepath="${HOME}/ls_colors/monokai.sh"
  if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
    source "$filepath"
  fi
fi
```